# Get value from pivot table is not working properly

Tags: laravel

I have a form for a user enter some info to do a registration in a congress.

In the form there is this part to show the required attribute only if the custom question has the column "required" with the value "1":

```
  @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
        <p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion->required }}</p>
        <p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion->ticket_type->pivot->required}}</p>
         <p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion}}</p>
        <input type="text" @if($customQuestion->required == "1") required @endif
           class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value="">

    </div>
  @endforeach
```

But its not working because "`{{$customQuestion->required }}`" in "`<p>REQUIRED VALUE:::::: {{$customQuestion->required }}</p>`" is `null`, dont shows nothing.

The "`{{$customQuestion}}`" shows:

```
{"id":1,
 "question":"Whats your phone?",
 "type":"text","congress_id":1,
 "pivot":{"ticket_type_id":1,
 "question_id":1},
 "ticket_type":[{"id":1,
 "name":"test",
 "congress_id":1,
 "pivot":{"question_id":1,
 "ticket_type_id":1,"required":1}}]}
```

The "`{{$customQuestion->ticket_type->pivot->required}}`" shows: "`Property [pivot] does not exist on this collection instance.`".

Do you know why `$customQuestion->required` is null?

Models relevants for the question:

```
// Congress model
class Congress extends Model
{

    // A congress has many ticket types
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// TicketType Model

class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions');
    }
}

// TicketTypeQuestion model

class TicketTypeQuestion extends Model
{

}

class Question extends Model
{

    public function ticket_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
}
```

Table relationships relevans for the question:

```
1 to many between congress and ticket types (a congress can have many ticket types)
1 to many between ticket types and ticket_type_questions (a ticket type can have many custom questions)
1 to many between questions and ticket_type_questions (a question can be associated with many ticket types)
```

The ticket_type_questions table has this structure: `id, ticket_type_id, question_id, required`. The required column is 1 if the custom question is required for that ticket type and 0 if is not required.

The "`$selectedTypes`" comes from the RegistrationController storeUserInfo() method:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){

            $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

            $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

            foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){
                if($quantity) {
                    $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
                    $price = $ttype->price;

                    $selectedType[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
                    $selectedType[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
                    $selectedType[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
                    $selectedType[$ttype->name]['questions'] = $ttype->questions;

                }
            }
            Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
            Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
            Session::put('customQuestions' ,  $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['questions']);
            //dd($selectedTypes);
            return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
        }
```

Comment: Try `{{$customQuestion->pivot->required }}`

Comment: Thanks, is also null, dont show nothing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the pivot is on the related model, not on the original (as there are many pivots). What I posted wouldn't make sense.

Comment: What's `$selectedType`? Which model is it referring to?

Comment: Thanks I update the question. The $selectedTypes comes from the RegistrationController storeUserInfoMethod that stores some stuff and then returns the user to the registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `->withPivot(..)` to your `TicketType` `questions()` relationship:

```
class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot(['required']);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}
```